# Maven project reads file in IDE but not from JAR

Tags: java, maven

I write a method to use a Scanner object to read from a file (the file name is "test.txt" and it is in the resources folder) and return a String.
When I run the project in the IDE it works fine and the String is returned successfully, but when I compile it to a JAR and run it from the terminal it returns null instead, as if it's not reading the file properly.
What should happen is that it should return the string.

I've only encountered this issue on Maven projects.
Have not tested it without Maven, but it looks like the same issue occurs whether I compile with Maven or IntelliJ

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main mainTest = new Main();
        System.out.println(mainTest.test());
    }

    private String test() {
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt")).getPath());

        try (
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)
        ) {
            String line = "";

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            return line;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: change file name from "test.txt" to "src/main/resources/test.txt" and check, I assumed your file is at "src/main/resources"

Comment: @dkb - nope, if the resource was at src/main/resources/test.txt, above code would be perfectly valid. Never refer to `src/` at runtime in a mavenized project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as soon as you package the application as a jar, the file you are trying to load becomes a file stored inside a zip file rather than a file that exists somewhere on your filesystem. That is a fundamental difference in the runtime environment and one of the classic gotchas when it comes to working with files stored on the classpath.

Use [getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) instead, that always works as long as the file is stored in the same module where the class is stored (in the same jar, in this case).

Scanner has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)) which accepts an InputStream. So something like:

```
try(InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt")) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
    // do things with stuff here
}
```